# Only zeros as assignment values in a simpleKMeans clustering

Tags: java, instance, cluster-analysis, weka, k-means

I am writing a code that uses traffic data, stores it in an OD Matrix, and displays it as a heatmap. I am trying to cluster (k-means for now) it but for some reason my instances' assignments are only zeros.
This is my code:

```
public class Clustering {

Vector <ODData> myData = new Vector <ODData>();
int capacity;
int ROUTES_SIZE = 324263;

public Clustering( ODData [] routes, int cap )
{
    capacity = cap;
    for (ODData s : routes) 
        {
            myData.add(s);
        }       
}

public void Build_cluster()
{

    Attribute x1 = new Attribute("Beginning point x"); 
    Attribute y1 = new Attribute("Beginning point y");
    Attribute x2 = new Attribute("End point x"); 
    Attribute y2 = new Attribute("End point y");
    Attribute dem = new Attribute("Demand");

    ArrayList <Attribute> attribute_list = new ArrayList <Attribute>(5); 
    attribute_list.add(x1); 
    attribute_list.add(y1); 
    attribute_list.add(x2);
    attribute_list.add(y2); 
    attribute_list.add(dem); 

    Instances attribute_instance = new Instances ("Cluster", attribute_list, capacity);

    double [] temp_array = new double[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < myData.size(); i++)
    {
        ODData s;
        s = myData.get(i);
        temp_array[0] = s.getOrigin().getLattitude();
        temp_array[1] = s.getOrigin().getLongititude();
        temp_array[2] = s.getDestination().getLattitude();
        temp_array[3] = s.getDestination().getLongititude();
        temp_array[4] = s.getValue();

        Instance inst = new DenseInstance( 1, temp_array );
        attribute_instance.add(inst);
    }

    SimpleKMeans Kmeans_clustering = new SimpleKMeans();
    Kmeans_clustering.setPreserveInstancesOrder(true);

    try {
        Kmeans_clustering.buildClusterer(attribute_instance);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    /*Sorting by groups*/


    int[] assignments = new int[ROUTES_SIZE];
    try {
        assignments = Kmeans_clustering.getAssignments();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Any idea why I get only zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For k-means you need to specify the **number of clusters**.

I guess this defaulted to 1 cluster (with ID 0).

P.S. for your data (latitude, longitude, demand), k-means does not make a whole lot of sense. You need to define a distance that measures the similarity as you need it for your data (data specific!), then use a distance based clustering algorithm.